# ActionScript - Automatic Test Cases for Zooming and Panning

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, zooming, testcase, panning

I have a very easy application in both AS3 and C++ (for mobile version) which shows a map of New York and allows the user to pan, zoom and receive information boxes when clicking on an attraction on the map.

My question is: how could I write simple test functions to check whether the panning and zooming are working?

Comment: What is your IDE? Why not just test on a mobile device?

Comment: I wouldn't mind the IDE. It could be even Notepad. I would just like to know the best way to make sure the panning and zooming functions I have work. I would like to build a testing framework to automatize such things so that I don't have to test it manually on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I use flash Professional CC it has a great Emulator for testing Touch devices on a PC.

but for what you want you might want to use something like

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
```

check out: [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

or detect and send using trace gesture events for your testing purposes.